# Draggable sine function, click, move and release

Tags: python-3.x

Someone has an example to learn how is possible to do a draggable sine function with matplotlib?
I have multiple graphs on the same figure with different axis, I need to adjust the position for every graph using the mouse, click and keeping pressed the right button should be possible to move the graph selected.
Or in alternative to do an automatic adjustment of the offset for every graph.